# jQuery date format not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, date-formatting

I am using jQuery datepicker for my project. I have this code:

```
$('#date-show').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
```

My gripe is that although the datepicker shows, the date format is still 'mm-dd-yyyy') and I had also tried

```
$('#date-show').datepicker("option","dateFormat","dd-mm-yy");
```

It still displays as mm-dd-yyyy. Am I missing out something?

Comment: The format mantains 'mm-dd-yyyy' format each date you pick in the calendar, or you're sending a 'mm-dd-yyyy' format data to the component in the load time and it's not assimilating? Your second code is correct anyway.

Comment: @ExcubeDzynes, Did you check the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the problem you has was with day/month or with the number of digits for year, but this code works:

```js
$('#date-show').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="date-show" name="date-show" />
```

If you need the year to be 2 digits (instead of 4) you should use only 1 `y` (and not 2).

```js
$('#date-show').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-y' });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="date-show" name="date-show" />
```

Comment: Not sure who the downvoter is, but it will be great to get an explanation for the downvote

Comment: I was sure his problem is with `mm-dd` vs `dd-mm`. The `yy` is for 4 chars year. If he wants 2 he can use only 1 `y`.

Comment: @epascarello, answer updated, I think you can change the downvote

Comment: @ExcubeDzynes, if the answer is correct you should I would appreciate it if you accept/vote it up. If it doesn't solve your problem please try to add more information/code sample and I'll try to help.

Comment: it doesn't work for me but I surmise it works in jsFiddle, so I'll accept it